# Cannot connect to mysql server in El Capitan

Tags: mysql, osx-elcapitan

I want to learn joomla and so far i've followed the instructions online on how to enable the apache and php on my El Capitan mac but im having issues with MySQL.
I downloaded the dmg file and installed MySQL and also installed the phpmyadmin files.
Started the apache and mysql server.

phpmyadmin webpage loads, instructions are followed carefully
but for some reason i can not login into the phpmyadmin with the root and temp password from the installation.
Also used the shell with many commands ( ex. mysql -v root -p ) but the temporary password never gets accepted.

Tried changing the password (from online help), nothing worked.

Tried every possible solution online but it seems php (from phpmyadmin or joomla installation) can not communicate with mysql or password never gets accepted. No idea.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried using your root username password. If you do `sudo su`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this link to reset the root password: http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/01/how-to-change-the-root-password-for-mysql-in-xampp/

And then try this login string `mysql -uroot -p`

It will prompt you for your password.  If this fails, try specifying the port and host.  ie `mysql -uroot -p -P3306 -h127.0.0.1`

Another method to set the root password, according to Google (I've never done it this way):

How can I set a root password in MySQL?
Configure it with the "XAMPP Shell" (command prompt). Open the shell from the XAMPP control pane and execute this command:
mysqladmin.exe -u root password secret
This sets the root password to 'secret'.

Comment: Sorry, after re-reading your question and the link I posted, I'm not sure this will help, as you said you can't seem to access phpmyadmin in the first place.  Please let me know if that is the case, and I will revise my answer if able.

Comment: I havent installed any bundle like XAMPP. Im trying to make it work natively  in El Capitan. So far apache and php work fine but i can't make mysql work...